# infinite shades of sonic gray

Tags: word-meaning

This is from [*The New York Times* article](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/06/18/arts/music/dad-rock.html).

> As a kid, the noodly, pristine sounds of Walter Becker and Donald
> Fagen signified nothing so much as my dad exerting oppressive control
> over the car stereo. Just infinite shades of **sonic gray** and songs
> that would never freaking end. Do it … again?! What else have you been
> doing for the last five and a half minutes of this song?

I wonder what the 'sonic gray' means here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article’s sub description says the author “*endured* her father’s music.” That, coupled with “songs that would never freaking end,” should clue you in on what “sonic gray” is referring to in this text. At the very least, it’s nothing good.

“Sonic” means, as any dictionary can tell you, “related to sound and sound waves.” “Gray” is sometimes used to denote something that is boring or dull. It’s not black, it’s not white, just kind of “meh.”

Put together, it seems that the author is describing the car music as very boring.

Comment: Thank you very much.